# Using $location for only part of a page breaks back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to use $location to navigate a self-contained comments section on a normal statically loaded page, but it seems to break the back back button.

The problem comes when I've navigated to a few pages using $location, then click on an external link. It goes to that link, but when I hit back, it changes the URL to the last one but doesn't actually change the page (i.e. it stays on the external page). If I then keep on clicking back, it changes the URL (so the url history is fine), but it doesn't actually load up the page from that url until I get to the first one that I've visited (if that makes sense...). So, for example:

So, navigating the app:

1. www.example.com - loads up my page with the comments
2. www.example.com?page=2 - uses $location and loads the new comments correctly
3. www.example.com?page=3 - uses $location and loads the new comments correctly
4. www.externalexamplepage.com - navigates correctly to the page.
5. back - changes the address to www.example.com?page=3 but stays on www.externalexamplepage.com
6. back - changes the address to www.example.com?page=2 but stays on www.externalexamplepage.com
7. back - changes the address to www.example.com and loads up the page correctly.

So, how can I get it to not break the back button? This is what I've got in my comments directive:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(e, newUrl) {    
    // If moving off current page...
    if ($scope.changingCommentsPage === false) {
        $window.location.href = newUrl;
    }
});

$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
    // Get current urlParams
    var urlParams = $location.search();

    // Get new comments if page has changed
    if ($scope.page != urlParams.page || typeof urlParams.page  === "undefined") {
        $scope.changingCommentsPage = false;
        $scope.page = urlParams.page ? urlParams.page : 1;
        if ($scope.page < 1) return;

        // Get comments
        getComments($scope.model.page);
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens if you type `www.example.com?page=3` in the browser?

Comment: @StefanFilip It goes to the right page and loads the comments as expected.